# Загрузка JDBC драйвера MSSQL в Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, classloader

Доброго времени суток.

**Задача:** Если попытаться получить соединений с БД на сервере Tomcat просто обычным способом

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=some_database",
    "some_user",
    "some_pasword"
);
```

то получим ошибку, где будет говорится, что подходящий драйвер для указанного URL не найден.
Но если перед получением соединения добавить строку

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

то все работает. Мне необходимо понять, хотя бы в общих чертах - почему первый способ не работает, а второй работает?

**Моя попытка ответить на это вопрос:** поискав в документации Tomcat, прочитав о загрузке классов - пришел к выводу, что дело в том, как организована загрузка классов и ресурсов в Tomcat. Я исходил из следующих посылок:

1. Как я понял, помимо трех стандартных загрузчиков, для каждого web приложения предоставляется свой собственный загрузчик сервером Tomcat.
2. Каждый загрузчик классов(в java платформе в целом) знает о существовании классов только в определенном для него контексте.
3. jar файл представляющий JDBC драйвер хранится внутри него по пути WEB_INF/lib, т.е. он известен только загрузчику классов персонально предоставленному именно данному web приложению.
4. метод Class.forName() загружает класс используя загрузчик классов загрузивший класс, внутри которого вызывается данный метод.

И пришел к следующим выводам:

1. метод DriverManager.getConnection() скорее всего не использует контекстный загрузчик классов, и тот не может найти JDBC драйвер.
2. Класс вызывающий метод Class.forName() был загружен загрузчиком классов предоставленному данному web приложению. Поэтому Class.forName() может отыскать JDBC драйвер. (Однако не понятно как DriverManager.getConnection() получает доступ к классу загруженному через Class.forName().)

**Вопрос:** скажите пожалуйста - верно ли я смог ответить на поставленный в задаче вопрос? И если нет - укажите пожалуйста где я ошибся, пропустил ли я что-то?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем верно. `DriverManager.getConnection()` будет пытаться загрузить драйвер используя загрузчик классов, но при этом будет искать класс драйвера используя системное свойство `jdbc.drivers`, например:

```
jdbc.drivers=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;
```

Если свойство пустое, то и загружать будет нечего (что у вас очевидно и происходит)

Comment: Почему тогда метод DriverManager.getConnection() находит драйвер после вызова Class.forName()? Class.forName() что-то записывает в системное свойство jdbc.drivers?

Comment: Да вы батенька совсем ку-ку :) 

Ну если серьезно работает это так: при выполнении кода, происходит следующее. Встречаем участок кода `DriverManager.getConnection()`, сначала ищем среди загруженных классов `DriverManager` (поскольку это интерфейс, он должен быть имплементирован драйвером). Если все хорошо (то есть драйвер был загружен) - работаем, если нет, ищем `jdbc.drivers` и оттуда получаем список классов драйверов и запускаем загрузчик классов.